# Why this mutil-threaded program is Segfaulting?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm playing around with a solution for the dinning philosophers problem using mutexes, however the program is segfaulting for probably a thread-related bug
 What i'm trying to do here is basically think of the fork as a mutex and creat a function `void *eat(void *arg)` , and then close the critical section (the critical section is just the thread declaring its id and that its currently eating) whatever the function gets called , then i loop through all my philosophers and check if its id (id's start from 0) divisible by 2. 
 First round just threads id's that are divisible by 2 eat and second round only threads id's that are not will eat and so on in an infinite loop .
I know this a stupidly simple solution which probably doesn't solve the problem in the first place. so please bear with me. if you have any questions please let me know in the comment.

```
struct typedef t_philo
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_mutex_t fork;
    int id;
}
t_philo;

void *eat(void *arg)
{
    t_philo *philo = (t_philo *)arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->fork);
    printf("philo with id: %i is eating\n", philo->id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->fork);
    return (NULL);
}

void first_round(t_philo *philo, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (!(i % 2))
            pthread_join(philo[i].thread, NULL);
}

void second_round(t_philo *philo, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if ((i % 2))
            pthread_join(philo[i].thread, NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_philo *philo;
    // how many philosophers is given as first arg.
    int len = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (argc < 2)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    philo = malloc(sizeof(*philo) * atoi(argv[1]));
    //this function add id's and initialize some data.
    init_data(philo, argv);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        pthread_create(&philo[i].thread, NULL, eat(&philo[i]), &philo[i]);

        while (1)
        {
            first_round(philo, len);
            second_round(philo, len);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
philo with id: 0 is eating
philo with id: 1 is eating
philo with id: 2 is eating
philo with id: 3 is eating
philo with id: 4 is eating
            .
            .
            .
            .
philo with id random is eating
[1]    29903 segmentation fault
```

Output reaches a random id each time and segfault, that's why i concluded it might be a thread bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_create` has this following prototype:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

`start_routine` is a *function pointer*. However, you call `pthread_create` with **wrong arguments**: `eat(&philo[i])`. Thus, the program calls `eat` correctly and then tries to **call `NULL`** (from a new thread) because this is the value returned by `eat`. The randomness comes from the variable time to actually create the threads.

Note that **using a debugger** should help you to find and fix the problem very easily. Debuggers like gdb are a bit hard to learn but once this is done, errors like segfault becomes almost easy to fix. I am also surprised a compiler like clang would not notice the typing issue at compile time.

Comment: Yeah missed that, i need to revise my basics , thank you. if you have any good resources regarding learning a debugger, please lighten.

Comment: There are documents/websites like [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/NETMF/llilum/gdbTutorial.pdf) or [this one](http://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial) but most of them are not very user-friendly. I personally learned on the job (during several years). That being said, in this case, I think is should not be too difficult to use gdb to find locate error: just compiling with `-g`, running the program with gdb and looking the stack should be enough. Note that gdb has a `--tui` mode for a console-based GUI that is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, `int len = argv[1];` is wrong. If you compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall`), this statement would be flagged by the compiler.

As is, you're getting a *huge* value for `len`. So, later, the `for` loop will overflow the array you allocate and you have UB.

You probably want: `int len = atoi(argv[1]);` as you have for the `malloc`.

And, you want to do this *after* the `argc` check.

And, why call `atoi` twice [with the fix]?

Here's the refactored code:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_philo *philo;

    if (argc < 2)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // how many philosophers is given as first arg.
    int len = atoi(argv[1]);

    philo = malloc(sizeof(*philo) * len);

    // do stuff ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry its not the problem i just minified my program for the sake of simplicity , in my long version i actually convert the length and other 3 parameters to integers and store them in a more or less effective way, this is just a short version of the program which spot light in the logic that matters ,the problem is bug related the program is running and segfaulting randomly at different ids . i'll correct the error sorry of the misleading.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and append a minimal version that _compiles_ cleanly and can generate the problem